# PLINQ and variable degree of parallelism in C#

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

Is it possible to modify the degree of parallelism during an execution of a PLINQ query? I want do do some heuristics that should significantly improve the overall performance, but the number of concurrent threads would be calculated during the execution.

```
mySequence.AsParallel()
    .WithDegreeOfParallelism(5) // <- that's what I want to modify
    .ForAll(...);
```

Or, if there is no such an option - is there any easy way for manipulating with the maximum number of parallel threads?

Comment: Im I understanding you in that you want to change the degree of parallelism while the query is running?

Comment: @Magnus Exactly, that is right.

Comment: I think the proper way to do this would be to write your own scheduler. Regarding manipulating the maximum number of parallel threads, `WithDegreeOfParallelism` *is* for specifying a maximum. There won't necessarily be exactly 5 threads operating at all times.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee789351.aspx